# Translate JSON field into controller DateTime parameter .NET WEB API

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api

When the following web api request is made,

[image]

The indicated Json fields will bind to the following properties

```
public DateTime AidCurrentPlannedDate { get; set; }
public DateTime AidNewPlannedDate { get; set; }
```

when the request is submitted, the following values are binded to the controller parameter properties, notice that instead of translating using the following format "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss" instead it seems the following format is being used "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss".

[image]

The following approach was tried to force the datetime binding in the way we expect (format "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss")

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Web.Mvc;

public class DateTimeBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        if (controllerContext == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("controllerContext", "controllerContext is null.");
        if (bindingContext == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("bindingContext", "bindingContext is null.");

        var value = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);

        if (value == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(bindingContext.ModelName);

        CultureInfo cultureInf = (CultureInfo)CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Clone();
        cultureInf.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss";

        bindingContext.ModelState.SetModelValue(bindingContext.ModelName, value);

        try
        {
            var date = value.ConvertTo(typeof(DateTime), cultureInf);

            return date;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            bindingContext.ModelState.AddModelError(bindingContext.ModelName, ex);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

```
using SadegeRestApi.Utils;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace SadegeRestApi
{
    public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

            ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(DateTime), new DateTimeBinder());
            ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(DateTime?), new DateTimeBinder());
        }
    }
}
```

However, the value binding did not change.

Is it possible to control the way the JSON field is translated into a DateTime property when the field is binded to a controller parameter? How could that be accomplished?

Comment: From [Model Binding in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-5.0#no-source-for-a-model-property) : Note that this [BindRequired] behavior applies to model binding from posted form data, not to JSON or XML data in a request body. Request body data is handled by input formatters.

Comment: In short, model binding isn't used with HTTP content (except forms content). You need specify the expected date time format in the desieralizer settings.

Comment: It's the classic ASP.NET? I don't know that, but I suppose is idem.

Comment: @vernou, this is a web api project with target .NET Framework 4.5. Could you guide me further on how/where I could change this desieralizer settings?

Answer (score 0):

In the sample code that follows, the intention is to convert a string into a DateTime using the following format/mask "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss".

To controll how a string is deserialized from JSON into C# DateTime data type, the following class was created

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;
using System;
using System.Globalization;

public class DateTimeConverter : DateTimeConverterBase
{
    private string _dateFormat;

    public DateTimeConverter(string dateFormat)
    {
        _dateFormat = dateFormat;
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        try
        {
            if (reader.Value != null && reader.Value.ToString().Trim() != string.Empty)
                return DateTime.ParseExact(reader.Value.ToString(), _dateFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        }
        catch
        {
        }
        return null;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        writer.WriteValue(((DateTime)value).ToString(_dateFormat));
    }
}
```

and the following line was added to method "Register" in file ".../App_Start/WebApiConfig.cs"

```
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new DateTimeConverter("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"));
```

so that file ".../App_Start/WebApiConfig.cs" looks like that

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;

namespace SadegeRestApi
{
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API configuration and services
            // Configure Web API to use only bearer token authentication.
            //config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
            //config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType));

            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
            
            config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(
             new DateTimeConverter("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"));
        }

    }
}
```